# Accessing child XML elements in Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to write some code to delete specific nodes within an xml file.

I want the code to delete specific nodes based on the attributes of their parents and children.

I want to delete `<ParameterGroup>` nodes whose parents are `<Task>` nodes with `name="Parameter Estimation"`, and who have children `<Parameter>` nodes with `value="some_string"`.

The `"some_string"` value in this case is: `"CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value"`

I have written a `for` loop which grants me access to the specific nodes that I want to delete, but when I try and combine into one path it doesn't work.

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {"c": "http://www.copasi.org/static/schema"}

parsed = etree.parse('ct.cps')

for task in parsed.xpath("//c:Task[@name='Parameter Estimation']", namespaces=NSMAP):
    for group in task.xpath(".//c:ParameterGroup[@name='FitItem']", namespaces=NSMAP):
        for parameter in group.xpath(".//c:Parameter[@value='CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value']", namespaces=NSMAP):
            print parameter.attrib['name']
```

The code above accesses the correct subelement. However, I want to combine those three levels into one path so that I can delete the `<ParameterGroup>` node.

Something like this:

```
for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Task[@name='Parameter Estimation']/ParameterGroup[@name='FitItem']/Parameter[@value='CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value']", namespaces=NSMAP):
    parsed.remove(a)
```

But whenever I try that, or similar, I get zero output or an error stating that the xpath is wrong.

Here is a link to the xml file in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6hga7nvmcd6rxx/ct.cps?dl=0

And here is a snippet from a relevant section:

```
<Task key="Task_19" name="Parameter Estimation" type="parameterFitting" scheduled="false" updateModel="true">
  <Report reference="Report_12" target="" append="1" confirmOverwrite="1"/>
  <Problem>
    <Parameter name="Maximize" type="bool" value="0"/>
    <Parameter name="Randomize Start Values" type="bool" value="0"/>
    <Parameter name="Calculate Statistics" type="bool" value="1"/>
    <ParameterGroup name="OptimizationItemList">
      <ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
        <ParameterGroup name="Affected Cross Validation Experiments">
        </ParameterGroup>
        <ParameterGroup name="Affected Experiments">
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Parameter name="LowerBound" type="cn" value="1e-06"/>
        <Parameter name="ObjectCN" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=New Model,Vector=Reactions[v1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=Kcat,Reference=Value"/>
        <Parameter name="StartValue" type="float" value="433.724"/>
        <Parameter name="UpperBound" type="cn" value="1e+03"/>
      </ParameterGroup>
      <ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
        <ParameterGroup name="Affected Cross Validation Experiments">
```

EDIT: I can't even access subelements below the `<Task>` node; this doesn't work (it gives zero output):

```
for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Task[@name='Parameter Estimation']/ParameterGroup[@name='FitItem']", namespaces=NSMAP):
    print a.attrib['name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've used the same `//` axis instead of `/` in the combined XPath to form an exact translation of nested `for` version of your codes :

```
//c:Task[@name='Parameter Estimation']//c:ParameterGroup[@name='FitItem']//c:Parameter[@value='bla..bla..']
```

Using `/` axis didn't work mainly because `ParameterGroup` is not *direct child* of `Task`. You have one other level before reaching `ParameterGroup` from `Task` :

```
//c:Task[@name='Parameter Estimation']/*/c:ParameterGroup[@name='FitItem']/......
```